# Excel keeps priority on Office Clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, clipboard, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working on different softwares and different workbooks at the same time.
I am copying a lot from software into workbooks or from workbooks to workbooks.
But the issue is that when I copy something in Excel, paste it in Google, copy something new in Google and want to paste it in Excel it will paste what I did copy before in Excel and not the new copy of Google.
Here is a small video that is showing this problem exactly.
https://i.gyazo.com/c5f87e5dc231e38f0ef30879a68dd0fb.mp4

I read many posts on the internet with the same problem and some has solutions, but they don't help. Mainly they are answering with the following link; https://www.technipages.com/office-turn-office-clipboard-on-off
But this isn't helping at all.

I use Excel everyday and this **VERY** annoying for me, an issue that is playing for years which is slowing my work performance.

It has nothing to do with the software that I use or my computer.
The problem is always, with any program or computer.

Comment: what is the exact version of your Excel and OS? Do you have the same issue with other office tools too?

Comment: Excel 2016 & Windows 10. But so far I can remember it also on other Excel Versions and other OS. This is only happening with Excel.
Video is not even mine, but someone with same problem but he also didn't get working solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this conflicts happens because of a stupidity in windows Clipboard Manager! Most of the users does not have this problem, Don't know why this happens but this 2 ways should help you:

1. Use a clipboard manger software. I myself had used ClipX once, it had solved this kind of problems! Because it could understand that what I copied just now has the priority above all else!

You can find ClipX  [here](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) .

And if it couldn't handle that try some other clipboard managers that suggested  [here](https://lifehacker.com/5298615/five-best-clipboard-managers) . Change some options if it needs to, try to make it work for all applications and layers, it's worth trying.

2. Reinstall your office or even your windows. If you have a reliable copy of windows and you are available to update it, you shouldn't encounter the problem after a fresh install.

Avoid using unknown or low reputation softwares/sources/torrents, sometimes they will damage windows registry for ever, and even if you uninstall them, the harm would not be healed.

Comment: You are my hero, ClipX is doing his job perfect.
I need to say that I have this issue with any computer, any version and I really got the feeling that it is really something to do with Excel.
Can you please confirm if you have the same problem with Excel without any clipboard manager?

Comment: @ChrisToxz > Happy to hear that the pain is relieved :) , I can say that most of the times I hadn't any problem working with Excel & the clipboard, but sometimes it happened in some Excel/OS versions. Then a smarter clipboard manager could handle that!